# OPEN PANEL AND SHOW OPEN STREET MAP - Creatio and OSM

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap

I need to make it open a panel with Open Street Map on it but my code is not working, when I click on the button I added, it gets the loading screen but doesn't show anything and the console shows an error.

My Code:

```
{
    showMapContainer: function() {
        var mapsConfig = {
            mapsData: []
        };
        
        mapsConfig.mapsData.push(
            {
                address: "0.0, 0.0",
                content:"<h2>Check-In</h2>",
                gpsE: "0.0",
                gpsN: "0.0",
                isCoordsItem: true,
                useCurrentUserLocation: true
            }
        );
        MapsUtilities.open({
            mapsConfig: mapsConfig,
            scope: this
        });
    }
}
```

Error: [image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, I needed to add the GetMapsConfig in messages:

```
...
    messages: {
        "GetMapsConfig": {
            mode: Terrasoft.MessageMode.PTP,
            direction: Terrasoft.MessageDirectionType.SUBSCRIBE
        }
    },
...
```